# propel - JoinWith and use Query

Tags: php, join, propel

What is a diference beetween JoinWith, and useTablenameQuery ?  How    its work in propel, why JoinWith is faster than useTable_nameQuery ?     How work formatter ?  Thanks for help :

)

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is when you have filter specifically for the on the right like `TableB=?`

**joinWith:** Default Join condition as defined in the schema

```
$rows = TableAQuery::create()
    ->joinWith('TableB')
    ->find();
```

**useTableBQuery** Use a filter for the table right

```
$rows = TableAQuery::create()
    ->useTableBQuery()
        ->filterByColumnName($value) // A column in TableB
    ->endUse()
    ->filterByColumnName($value2) // A column in TableA
    ->find();
```

Notice the second `->filterByColumnA()` is outside the `->useTablBQuery`, to illustrate that you can have filter on both tables